# Zipping a directory to a remote location in Java

Tags: java, zip

I'm trying to create a zip file from a directory in Java, then place that file on a remote server (a network share).  I'm currently getting an error because the Java `File` object cannot reference a remote location and I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Is there a way to zip a directory in Java to a remote location without using the File class?

Comment: Just a question: What do you mean with a remote location? The java.io.File(String) constructor (Java 6) accepts network shares, i.e. new File("\\\\rootdomain.es\\folder1\\folder2\\").list()

Comment: @ATorras It's in the format "file:///C:/SomePath"...I was under the impression that wouldn't work...will new File(\\\\C:\SomePath).list() do the trick?  I apologize for my "newbie" questions...I'm horribly unfamiliar with things like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the ZIP file locally and use either [`commons-net`](http://commons.apache.org/net/) FTP or SFTP to move the ZIP file across to the remote location, assuming that by *"remote location"* you mean some FTP server, or possibly a blade on your network.

If you are using the **`renameTo`** method on `java.io.File`, note that [this **doesn't work** on some operating systems (e.g. Solaris)](http://www.coderanch.com/t/439021/Java-General/java/File-renameTo-Failing-Solaris) where the locations are on different shares. You would have to do a manual copy of the file data from one location to another. This is pretty simple using standard Java I/O.